# Display record even if it doesn't exist in DB

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a table with below data.

```
**Priority**    **Mydate**              **ID**
Critical       2018/01/20               1090
High           2018/01/27               1091
High           2018/01/18               1092
High           2018/01/24               1093
Low            2017/09/28               1083
```

Requirement is to fetch last 12 months record for all priority type(Critical, High, Medium and Low) and its count. If any of the priority type doesn't exist in DB for a particular month then display zero instead actual count.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Mydate, 'MM/YYYY') AS Mydate, PRIORITY, count(*)
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE Mydate >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), - 12)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(Mydate, 'MM/YYYY'), PRIORITY
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(Mydate, 'MM/YYYY') ASC, PRIORITY ASC;
```

With above query i can only achieve this :

```
Mydate      PRIORITY        Count
---------------------------------
01/2018     High            3
01/2018     Critical        1
09/2017     Low             1
```

Expected result is :

```
Mydate      PRIORITY        Count
---------------------------------
01/2018     Critical        1
01/2018     High            3
01/2018     Medium          0
01/2018     Low             0
09/2017     Critical        0
09/2017     High            0
09/2017     Medium          0
09/2017     Low             1
```

Comment: The partitioned outer join syntax solves this problem https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/analysis.htm#DWHSG02013

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the rows using a `cross join`.  Then use `left join` and `group by` to finalize the query:

```
select p.priority, ym.yyyymm, count(*) as cnt
from (select distinct priority
      from t
     ) p cross join
     (select distinct to_char(my_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm
      from t
      Mydate >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), - 12)
    ) ym left join
    (select t.*, to_char(my_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm
      from t
     ) t
     on t.priority = p.priority and t.yyyymm = ym.yyyymm
group by p.priority, ym.yyyymm;
```

Note that this uses subqueries to get the priorities and months.  You can use other methods (such as a reference table or explicitly listing the values).